# Can I eat humans and sacrifice them to my god?

Tags: nethack

If I am a race other than human and lawful, can I eat humans and sacrifice them or will this hurt my alignment?

Or is that only a problem if you are human?

Comment: @Robotnik what can I say Nethack makes it easy ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, it should be safe to do so under typical circumstances.**

To the best of my knowledge, the only thing that matters for [cannibalism](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Cannibalism) and [sacrifice](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Sacrifice#Sacrificing_creatures_of_own_race) purposes is whether the creature being eaten/sacrificed is the same race as you; human-type monsters aren't given any special status in those regards if you're not playing as a human. (Human-type monsters are, however, treated as a special case for some other things; for example, [genociding a human-type species can affect your alignment record](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Human_%28monster_attribute%29), and killing peacefully-generated humans is always [murder](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Murder).)

Therefore, if you're not human, you should be safe to eat and sacrifice all the fresh human corpses you want, all other race- and alignment-specific caveats notwithstanding.

(It should also be noted that these rules aren't affected by polymorph; what matters is your *innate* race and not your polymorphed form, so eating a human corpse while playing as a non-human that's currently polymorphed into a human is still OK.)